# Bind input checkbox's property checked to a field

Tags: javascript, html, kendo-listview

I need to prepare a kendo listView in which each item is an input checkbox like shown in image.[image]

This listView is bound a to a list of objects having two properties: "Title" & "IsChecked"

I have used the following template to prepare this listView:

```
    <script type="text/x-kendo-tmpl" id="checkBoxListTemplate">

                <div style='margin-left:5px;'>
                    <label style='font-weight: normal;'>
                        <input type="checkbox" />#: Title#
                    </label>
                </div>
            </script>

var _data = [];
_data.push({"Title" : "123", "IsChecked" : true});
_data.push({"Title" : "ABCD", "IsChecked" : false});

var _dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    data: _data 
});


    $("#lstView").kendoListView({
                dataSource: _dataSource,
                template: kendo.template($("#checkBoxListTemplate").html())
            });
```

As can be seen in template, "Title" property is bound to display the content of checkbox but I need to bind the checked property of input to "IsChecked" field so that if its true, then checkbox should appear as checked or unchecked if false depending on the value of the property.

How can checkbox's checked property be bound to "IsChecked" field?

One more question.. Is it possible to have two way binding such that If I manually check/uncheck the checkbox, its value will be changed for "IsChecked" property in the dataSource ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use conditions inside kendo template like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" #if(IsChecked){# checked="checked" #}# />
```

Here is the working code snippet.

```js
var _data = [];
  _data.push({
    "Title": "123",
    "IsChecked": true
  });
  _data.push({
    "Title": "ABCD",
    "IsChecked": false
  });
  var _dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    data: _data
  });
  $("#lstView").kendoListView({
    dataSource: _dataSource,
    template: kendo.template($("#checkBoxListTemplate").html())
  });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.1.223/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.1.223/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="lstView">
  <script type="text/x-kendo-tmpl" id="checkBoxListTemplate">

                <div style='margin-left:5px;'>
                    <label style='font-weight: normal;'>
                        <input type="checkbox" #if(IsChecked){# checked="checked" #}# />#: Title#
                    </label>
                </div>
            </script>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: One more question.. Is it possible to have two way binding such that If I manually check/uncheck the checkbox, its value will be changed for "IsChecked" property in the dataSource  ?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. For that you need to use CRUD Data Operations: http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/datasource/crud  and use `autoSync`.